# Good method to compute product of the most common integers in a list?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an array of n integers and I am supposed to return
the product of most common integers.

Example: (2,3,4,2,2,1,4)- returns 8.

I can use normal arrays to store the values.

If I want to have runtime optimization, should I use hashtable in C# or dictionary?
Will that help me have space optimization as well? 
Or is there any other approach to have space optimization?

Comment: Protip: make it work first, _then_ optimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have speed optimisation or space optimisation, but not both.

If you want space optimisation you can sort the array, then loop through it to look for the longest sequence of the same value. This will need very little storage except the array, but it will change the original array. Sorting would generally be O(n log n), and then looping would be O(n).

If you want speed optimisation, you can use a dictionary to count the occurances, then get the largest count. This would need by average n * 10 bytes for the dictionary, but it leaves the original array unchanged. Counting would be close to O(n), and finding the largest count would be O(n).

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Could you please explain O(n logn) for the sorting a bit?

Comment: The `Array.Sort` method is O(n log n) by average: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx6zbd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is so contrived that it looks like homework, so I'm just going to roughly describe how I'll do it. Then you can try something, and come back if you got any questions about it.

I would associate in a table of some sorts (a `Dictionary<int, int>` is the simplest choice) the numbers with how many times they were encountered. Then it's just a matter of taking the one with the highest count (let's call that count `n` from now on) and multiplying that number with itself `n` times.